# What this error "not all arguments converted during string formatting" means?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am entering two numbers from the user to get the GCD.
Error showing at `return gcd(a,a%b)`

Attach is the code

```
def gcd(a,b):
   if b==0:
      return a
   return gcd(a,a%b)


a = input("Enter first number: ")
b = input("Enter second number: ")
res = gcd(a,b)
print("GCD of {1} and {2} is {3}".format(a, b,res))
```

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: You aren't converting input string to number.... Try `a = int(input("Enter first number: "))` and for `b` too

Comment: Mention the python version please. For me, just removing the 1,2,3 from print statement worked. I am using Python 3.7.

Comment: That didn't work. The error changed to "tuple index out of range" at line 10

Comment: remove 1,2 and 3

Comment: did you try after removing that. I faced the same error and was resolved after removing the numbers from print

Comment: Duplicate: [How can I read inputs as numbers?](/q/20449427/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems:

1. The function `input()` returns a string. So you need to convert the result to a number or integer using `int()`.
2. The algorithm is wrong. The recursive call should be `return gcd(b, a%b)`.
3. The positional placeholders in `format()` are zero based. So the correct placeholders are `{0}`, `{1}` and `{2}`

The fixed code is:

```
def gcd(a,b):
   if b==0:
       return a
   return gcd(b, a%b)


a = int(input("Enter first number: "))
b = int(input("Enter second number: "))
res = gcd(a,b)
print("GCD of {0} and {1} is {2}".format(a, b, res))
```